# Can a single record from a polymorphic model belong to two (or more) models at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

General newbie question: If I have a polymorphic model called `Message`, and two other models called `Filter` and `User` with `has_many: messages, as ...` association on both. Can a single record from `Message` belong to `User` and `Filter` models at the same time? For example, can I do:

```
...
User.find(1).messages << Message.find(1)
Filter.find(1).messages << Message.find(1)
...
```

and have `Message#1` available in in `User#1` and `Filter#1`? The [RailsGuides gives a very brief explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), so this aspect is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Let's say a message has owner (that can be User or some other class) and processor (that can be Filter or some other class)
Then in the messages table you'll need columns: `owner_id, owner_type, processor_id, processor_type`.
And the classes should look something like:

```
class Message
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :processor, polymorphic: true
end

class User
  has_many :messages
end

class Filter
  has_many :messages
end
```

However in order to make the message belong to both models you'll need to do something like this:

```
Message.create(owner: User.find(1), processor: Filter.find(1))
# or like this
User.find(1).messages << Message.create(processor: Filter.find(1))
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I'm curious: Is the `polymorphic: true` declaration necessary? Would it not still work with all you code identical except both `polymorphic: true` removed?

Comment: @Bazley, `polymorphic: true` is NOT necessary if `User` and `Filter` classes are the only ones that can be `owner` and `processor` of a `Message` instance.

When I have answered the question I have been under the impression, that an owner of a message can be another class for example `Admin` or whatever and you can have different types of `Filter` classes.