# Rails polymorphic association showing in console but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, parent-child, polymorphic-associations, rails-console

I'm having a problem trying to match polymorphic association in an app I'm developing, between a User and a Recipe's Dietary Requirements. In the console, I can get this to work - if I match a user with the dietary_requirement_ids equalling '[2]' to a recipe with the same children, it works.

However, when I run the app, despite calling the same user and recipe, the method comparing the two evaluates to 'false'.

Hope that's clear, here's a little code to explain this:

**In the console**

```
one = User.first
two = Recipe.first
one.dietary_requirement_ids.any? && ((one.dietary_requirement_ids & two.dietary_requirement_ids) == one.dietary_requirement_ids)
# returns true, as it should
```

**However, in the view...**

I use a helper method accessible to the view, as follows:

```
  def dietary_requirement_matcher(one, two)
    one.dietary_requirement_ids.any? && ((one.dietary_requirement_ids & two.dietary_requirement_ids) == one.dietary_requirement_ids)
  end
```

as such:

```
<% Recipe.all.each do |recipe| %>
    <li><%= dietary_requirement_matcher(@user, recipe) %></li>
  <% end %> 
<!-- which all return false, including those that shouldn't! -->
```

---

I've no idea why it'll return the correct result in the console but not the view. I've tried a couple of things to debug this, as follows:

Changing the helper method to the following evaluates the recipes correctly (i.e. subbing out the user for the correct dietary_requirement_ids):

```
def dietary_requirement_matcher(one, two)
  ([1, 2] & two.dietary_requirement_ids) == [1, 2]
end
```

`@user.inspect` pulls up the correct user. However, `@user.dietary_requirement_ids.inspect` pulls up an empty array (despite still working in console).

I've checked the user and recipes are both saved correctly in the console.

---

Here's a little extra code that might be handy in working this out:

**Models**

Recipe

```
has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :classifiable
```

User

```
has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :classifiable
```

Dietary Requirement

```
belongs_to :classifiable, polymorphic: true
```

**Controller**

```
@recipes = Recipe.all
@user = current_user #auth method - debug shows this picking up the correct user in the view, albeit not their dietary requirements
```

**View** (incomplete, for debugging while I fix this)

```
<ul>
  <% Recipe.all.each do |recipe| %>
    <li><%= recipe.name %> = <%= dietary_requirement_matcher(@user, recipe) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<p><%= dietary_requirement_matcher(@user, Recipe.first) %></p> <!-- returns false, when I'm after true -->
<p><%= @user.dietary_requirements.inspect %></p> <!-- returns '#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>' -->
```

---

I reckon the fix for this is probably *really* simple, I'm just not spotting this as I'm an ignorant newbie. If anyone can help, I'll be very greatful! Steve.

---

**EDIT**

Doing a bit more digging, I've got a feeling this might be a problem with the way the app is looking for the information in the database. I'm running similar logic with has-many-through relationships for User (via Fridge) and Recipe Ingredients (which works!) and the log shows a different path to accessing the two pieces of info.

I *think*, because the polymorphic relationship looks for a classifiable_id and (crucially) a classifiable_type when hunting the database, the classifiable type is getting mixed up here. I've a feeling the SQLite is looking for the User's Dietary Requirements, but with the classifiable_type of 'Recipe' rather than 'User'.

Anyone able to shed any light on my thinking here? Any sense there or the ramblings of a madman? Here's the log as the page loads:

```
Started GET "/fridges/meals" for 151.229.93.203 at 2015-02-17 16:26:42 +0000
Processing by FridgesController#meals as HTML
#code for matching User Ingredients to Recipe Ingredients      
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "recipes"
  Recipe Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"
  Ingredient Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  Fridge Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "fridges".* FROM "fridges" WHERE "fridges"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "fridge_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "fridge_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "fridge_ingredients"."fridge_id" = ?  [["fridge_id", 5]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  Ingredient Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  Ingredient Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "fridge_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "fridge_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "fridge_ingredients"."fridge_id" = ?  [["fridge_id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  Ingredient Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 3]]
  Ingredient Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 4]]
  Rendered shared/_matcher.html.erb (21.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "fridge_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "fridge_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "fridge_ingredients"."fridge_id" = ?  [["fridge_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "fridge_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "fridge_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "fridge_ingredients"."fridge_id" = ?  [["fridge_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "ingredients".id FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ?  [["recipe_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["recipe_id", 4]]
#code for matching the User and Recipe Dietary Requirements
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  Recipe Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  ORDER BY "recipes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".id FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  DietaryRequirement Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "dietary_requirements".* FROM "dietary_requirements" WHERE "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_id" = ? AND "dietary_requirements"."classifiable_type" = ?  [["classifiable_id", 2], ["classifiable_type", "User"]]
  Rendered fridges/meals.html.erb within layouts/application (42.3ms)
  Cuisine Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cuisines".* FROM "cuisines"
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (3.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 593ms (Views: 579.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking, it could be the way your polymorphic association is set up:  Dietary Requirement can either belong to a `User`, or a `Recipe` because you are using `:classifiable` reference column on both. I have had a similar issue, and my solution was adding two separate reference columns to a polymorphic class like so:

- **DietaryRequirement** `belongs to :owner, polymorphic: true`, `belongs to :processor, polymorphic: true`. Then add the following columns to the `Dietary_Requirements` table: `owner_id, owner_type, processor_id, processor_type`.
- **Recipe**. `has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :processor`
- **User**. `has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :owner`

Comment: Thanks @Dimitry_N - I was hoping to avoid restructuring the model if possible, as it's working fine everywhere else. In the console, I can access both Users and Recipes with a single shared Dietary Requirement (i.e. both contain 'Vegetarian', ID: 2), it's just getting that to transfer to the view I'm struggling with. Does this make sense to you? Continuing below...

Comment: Please let me know if I'm just getting myself confused, but my understanding  was that using a polymorphic relationship was meant to negate the need for extra columns. Is this not the case? (Elsewhere I've just used two join models for has-many-throughs, and life is *so* much simpler!) I've added the logs of how the page looks at data as it loads, hope this helps shed some light on the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Another update - I've had a look into what you're saying, and the shared DR has the classifiable_type 'Recipe', while SQLite is looking for a classifiable_type 'User'. Is there a way to override this, or do I need to adjust as you've suggested? Thanks for the help - it seems to have got me to the route of the problem and helped my understanding a load. Will work on a solution now.

Comment: I hear you). I think the main reason to use polymorphic associations is to avoid creating unnecessary join tables. In you case it would be UserDitetaryRequrements and RecepieDietaryRequirements vs. using a polymorphic association with three classes and no join tables. And yes, you can adjust the type any way you want. Here is a similar question I posted on SO some time ago. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073289/can-a-single-record-from-a-polymorphic-model-belong-to-two-or-more-models-at-t

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for all the help. I'll have a play and get back to you!